# htaccess redirect if URL contains a certain symbol

Tags: .htaccess

There is a link:

```
domain.com/ab+cd
```

Is it possible to redirect the user to

```
domain.com/category/ab+cd
```

but provided that redirect should work only for those links in which there is **+**

ab and cd is a variables, so link can be look like ../asd+dsa, and that link should redirect to ../*category*/asd+dsa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` symbol carries no special meaning in the URL-path, however, it is a special regex character, so needs to be backslash escaped.

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+\+[a-z]+)$ /category/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The pattern `[a-z]+` matches 1 or more letters `a` to `z`. Followed by a literal `+` (`\+`). Followed again by 1 or more letters.

If you are not using mod_rewrite for anything else then you can use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive instead. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/([a-z]+\+[a-z]+)$ /category/$1
```

Comment: It was informative, thank you. Here is an option for Cyrillic:
     RewriteRule ^([A-Яа-я-]+\+[A-Яа-я-]+)(/?)$ /category/$1 [R=302,L]

Comment: If you need this to be case-insensitive then you use the `NC` (`nocase`) flag instead of explicitly including the uppercase characters in the character class - if you wish.